# Database - determine functional dependencies

Tags: database, dependencies

I have come across problem on how to determine functional dependencies.

Let's say we have a table

```
A B C
1 2 2
1 3 2
1 4 2
2 5 2
```

How do I determine functional dependencies out of that table? The result according to some classmates is supposed to be

```
A->C
CB->A
AB->C
AC->B
```

But I unfortunately have no idea on how to solve this.. Could somebody help me a little bit please?

Comment: Maybe  I understand it now, at each row you look at which value is the same and which changed. Depending on which value changed and which not you determine dependencies. (for example Row 2. A is still same, and B changed, due to that combination of B and C determines A) But that doesn't answer why first row is A -> C

Answer (score 0):

**How to check single functional dependency**

To check that functional dependency *X1, X2, ..., Xn → Y* holds for the given data, you should:

1. Project data on *(X1, X2, ..., Xn, Y)*, i.e remove all other columns, and then, remove duplicate rows (if any).
2. Project data on *(X1, X2, ..., Xn)*. Notice, that *Y* is omitted this time.
3. Functional dependency holds if and only if the number of rows in the first projection is the same, as the number of rows in the second one.

Let's consider you example and check functional dependency *A → C*. The first projection before duplicate rows removed:

```
A C
1 2
1 2
1 2
2 2
```

Actual first projection:

```
A C
1 2
2 2
```

Second projection:

```
A
1
2
```

The number of rows in projections are the same, so *A → C* holds for this data.

Let's consider another example: *CB → A*. The first projection is the same as the original table (no columns was removed and no duplicate rows found). The second projection is:

```
A B
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 5
```

It contains the same number of rows as the first one, so *CB → A* also holds.

And the last example: *AC → B*. The first projection is the same as in previous example. The second one is:

```
A C
1 2
2 2
```

Oops, there are less rows than in the first projection, so *AC → B* does not hold for this data.

**How to find all functional dependencies**

To find all functional dependencies that hold for the given data:

1. Build a table of projection size for every subset of the columns.
2. Sort it by the decreasing projection size.
3. If the subset S has the same projection size as subset T, then *S → T\S* (where *T\S* is set difference).

Let's consider a *partial* table for this example:

```
4 ABC
4 AB
2 AC
2 A
```

From this partial table we could see that both *AB → C* and *A → C* holds.

You need complete table to find all functional dependencies for your data.

**Remark**

Have you noticed recurring *functional dependencies for the given data* stance? The sample data may prove that a functional dependency is invalid. But a functional dependency that holds for the given data could still be invalid from the viewpoint of all possible data sets.